# undefined fetching data from firebase

Tags: reactjs

I have a small problem when I try to retrieve data from Firestore. The first result gives me undefined and then I have my results. The problem is that I can't make a .map because it tells me that users is undefined.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState()

    useEffect(() =>{

        const db = Firebase.firestore()
        db.collection('users').get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
            setUsers({ users: data });
            console.log(users);
        })
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                USERS
            </p>
            <div>
                {
                    users.map(user => {
                        <p>{user.name}</p>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWbdB.png)

Do you have any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users in your example **is** undefined.

To define a default value for a useState hook, you type it into the paranthesis. Try replacing your first line with the example below:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState({users: []}) //defines the default state of users

//or

const [users, setUsers] = useState( [] )
```

Additionally, you seem to switch between using `users` and `users.users`. Pick one approach and stick to it.

Below is a complete example of how I would approach this:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const db = Firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('users').get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
            setUsers(data);
            console.log(users);
        })
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <p>
            USERS
        </p>
        <div>
            {users.map(user => <p>{user.name}</p>}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Your answer will obviously solve the problem of `map of undefined` but its not the complete answer why that problem is ocuuring

Comment: @Shubh Feel free to post an alternative answer.

Comment: Perfect, it's working properly now! Thank you! @tim

Comment: @ZeDOver Very welcome + Happy hacking. Please don't forget to select the answer as the Accepted Answer if you have found it helpful.